# Is there a way to use OCR (python or java + linux terminal possible) to operate in real time?

Tags: java, python, input, inputstream, image-recognition

I'm starting to work on a program with python (could switch to java no prob) that uses Optical character recognition, but the only obvious method that this utilizes is importing image files, is there a way to instead have it running in real time on certain parts of the screen or is a cropping/snipping tool as good as I can hope for? Also, Is there a tool, library, language or approach I could use for something like this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. Lot of applications do that. However, to answer this in more detail would require lot more information. Are you working on a mobile app? A cloud service? A web app? A desktop client? there exists already software for this, have you considered that as a solution, or do you want to have your own?

Comment: @eis - I have planned to make this a desktop application. There is going to be a window on my screen that displays words (that can't be copied by cntrl + C) which I wish to analyze with "said" program and take that text as input.

Comment: Do note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." I'm not sure if this question fits the rules.